# What are good ways to highlight Tabs with color in Vim on Putty?

Tags: vim, highlight, putty

I always use putty to connect to Linux machines. I really want to make the Tabs in file visible in Vim.

I can have the Tabs highlighted in Gvim with the scripts below.

```
syntax match Tab /\t/
hi Tab gui=underline guifg=blue ctermbg=blue
```

However **Vim with Putty**, it doesn't work. I try to change gui to cterm, guifg to ctermfg. But still not work.

I know there is other way to make Tabs visible like the scripts below. The tabs will be displayed with ">----". However I don't prefer this way.

```
set lcs=tab:>-
set list!
```

Do you guys know any way to highlight Tabs with color in Vim on Putty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [spacehi.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=443) plugin works for me in Putty connecting to a Linux machine.

Comment: This solution does work. Verified. Add the following lines: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost,FilterReadPost,FileReadPost,Syntax * SpaceHi` and `au FileType help NoSpaceHi`.

Answer (score 7):

`set list` allows you to see invisible characters, including tabs.

I added this stuff to [my vimrc](https://github.com/EvanHahn/dotfiles/blob/master/resources/vimrc) so that the characters look nicer:

```
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬
```

Comment: For some settings `ᐅ` looks even better

Answer (score 1):

The `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` options take a *color number*, not an English color name. Try `9`. The table of numbers and their *usual* meanings is in vim's online help `:help ctermfg`

Comment: Thanks for your response. It still **not** work. I tried _ctermfg=1_. I don't know the term type of the putty.

Comment: @user674641, you can see what `TERM` is set to with `echo $TERM` once you have logged in. I suggest just trying numbers until you find one you like.

Comment: Got it. Find something weird, if I add `syntax match TAB /\t/
hi TAB ctermbg=blue ctermfg=red` in ~/.vimrc, it does not work when I vim some file. However if I vim a file and then type `:source ~/.vimrc`, the tabs can be highlighted. Weird. Any clues?

Comment: @user674641, try starting vim, then type `:edit $MYVIMRC` -- this will edit what vim thinks it should be loading at startup. I'm pretty surprised at what you've described, and not sure how it could happen, but I'm hoping the `:edit $MYVIMRC` will give some clues.

Comment: @sarnold, the ~/.vimrc does load, other key maps in ~/.vimrc work fine. It seems it's related to how _syntax_ and _highlight_ work. I checked spacehi.vim and it also requires an `autocmd` script to make the function work. I'm new to the vim scripts and the internal logic of vim. Not understand the behavior..

Comment: @Han He, `syntax on` is executed in my system-wide vimrc files before my `~/.vimrc` file configures specific hilights. I wonder if you need to move a `syntax on` command higher up in your `~/.vimrc` file?

Comment: @sarnold, changing the place of `syntax on` doesn't help too. I can use `:scriptnames` command to see the sequence of the loading scripts. I read the vim help about syntax and have some findings. It's related to the syntax file for file type. Actually `syntax match TAB /\t/ hi TAB ctermbg=blue ctermfg=red` can work with txt file, the tabs are highlighted. But for files with type which has according syntax file, it doesn't work. That's to say, if I open a txt file, the tabs are highlighted, but if I open a C file, tabs are not highlighted. _(continue in next comment)_

Comment: When `syntax on` is executed, the syntax.vim is loaded and then if file is identified as a known type, a `aucmd` is executed to load the according syntax file which I believe will overrule self define syntax rule in .vimrc. From the result of `:scriptnames`, the syntax file is the last one loaded.

Comment: @Han He, excellent detective work; thanks especially for the `:scriptnames` command, that sounds _really_ useful. :) Thanks for responding with your findings.

Comment: One issue that may be causing a lot of the troubles mentioned above is that  the "syntax" command needs the "containedin=ALL" option. Try `syntax match TAB /\t/ containedin=ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround solution is if you do not prefer separate plugin..
Add the following scrpts in .vimrc:

```
function! HiTabs()
    syntax match TAB /\t/
    hi TAB ctermbg=blue ctermfg=red
endfunction
au BufEnter,BufRead * call HiTabs()
```

This will highlight all tabs even in vim help files....

Suggest use spacehi.vim.

Comment: I like this, but it's a little more useful if you add the "containedin=ALL" option to "syntax":
`function! HiTabs() 
    syntax match TAB /\t/ containedin=ALL
    highlight TAB ctermbg=red ctermfg=white cterm=underline
endfunction
au BufEnter,BufRead * call HiTabs()
`

Answer (score 0):

Search for the tab special character

```
/\t
```

Also make sure Search Highlighting is enabled

```
:set hlsearch
```